# Integral involving erf and exponential

Tags: definite-integrals, gaussian-integral, error-function

#### Problem

I would like to compute the integral:

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \text{erf}(ax+b) \exp(-(cx+d)^2) dx \tag{1}
\end{align}

I have been looking at this popular [table of integral of the error functions](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf), and also found [here](http://keithbriggs.info/documents/erf-integrals.pdf) the following expression:

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-(\alpha x+ \beta)^2} \text{erf}(\gamma x+\delta) dx = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\alpha} \text{erf} \left[ \dfrac{\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+ \gamma^2}} \right] \tag{2}
\end{align}

as well as:

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-\alpha^2 x^2} \text{erf}(\beta x) dx = \dfrac{\text{arctan}(\beta / \alpha)}{\alpha \sqrt{\pi}} \tag{3}
\end{align}

However the latter (3) is only a particular case of (1), which is what I am looking for. Do you know how to prove (2)? This might help me understand how to compute (1)? Or do you know how to compute (1)?

Comment: in the second integral : ${{e}^{-{{(\alpha x+\beta )}^{2}}}}$

Answer (score 2):

**Partial solution**

Define:
$$I\left( \delta  \right)=\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }{{{e}^{-{{(\alpha x+\beta )}^{2}}}}}\text{erf}(\gamma x+\delta )dx$$
now differentiate with respect to $\delta$
$$\begin{align}
  & \frac{dI}{d\delta }=\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }{{{e}^{-{{(\alpha x+\beta )}^{2}}}}}\frac{\partial }{\partial \delta }\left( \text{erf}(\gamma x+\delta ) \right)dx \\ 
 & \quad \quad =\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }{{{e}^{-{{(\alpha x+\beta )}^{2}}}}\left( \frac{2{{e}^{-{{\left( \gamma x+\delta  \right)}^{2}}}}}{\sqrt{\pi }} \right)}dx\  \\ 
 & \quad \quad =\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }{{{e}^{-{{(\alpha x+\beta )}^{2}}-{{\left( \gamma x+\delta  \right)}^{2}}}}}dx=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\left( \frac{\sqrt{\pi }{{e}^{-\frac{{{\left( \alpha \delta -\beta \gamma  \right)}^{2}}}{{{\alpha }^{2}}+{{\gamma }^{2}}}}}}{\sqrt{{{\alpha }^{2}}+{{\gamma }^{2}}}} \right) \\\end{align}$$
Finally, you can find that:
$$I\left( \delta  \right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\alpha }\textrm{erf}\left( \frac{\alpha \delta -\beta \gamma }{\sqrt{{{\alpha }^{2}}+{{\gamma }^{2}}}} \right)$$

Comment: The proof you presented is known; the problem lies with the lower limit of 0 instead of $-\infty.$  I upvoted anyway because the OP wants a proof of this formula too.

Comment: you are right, in fact i figured that lately,....may be i Should delete my answer??

Comment: Leave the answer -- it may inspire the OP or a reader to derive an answer, though I'm not too hopeful.

Answer (score 1):

[Owen's Table of Normal Integrals](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610918008812164?journalCode=lssp20) provides the indefinite integral

[image: Indefinite Integral]

Just insert your integration limits, replace the normalized Laplacians by the erf with a few steps and you are done. But the answer is not very useful as it involves 4 times Owen's T function...

For $c=1$ and $d=0$, [Owen's Table of Normal Integrals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL6N9.png) gives you a simplified answer but only for a few limits

[image: SpecialCase]

where the middle on appears to be yours.
Personally, I am still trying to get a derivation of these integrals which turns out to be really hard, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3657081/how-to-derive-this-integal-int-0-infty-phix-phiabxdx).